# In MySQL, How get I get the parameter name of a stored procedure's first input parameter?

Tags: java, mysql, database

Currently, I call a stored procedure and I supply a input parameter.  The stored procedure has the following code which calls the stored procedure and has a (?) for the input parameter.

I supply the input parameter by the way of: Callablestatement.setstring("some_parameter_name", "1234").  The problem is the parameter name is not being recognized by the database and I get a null pointer error.  However, if I use an index number such as 1 to replace the "some_parameter"name", this will work.

Ideally, I want to know why it isn't working and perhaps the DBA did not give me the right parameter name.  is there any way for me on the client side to know or figure out what the parameter name is?  So I can supply the input parameter based on a name, rather than by the index number?

Thanks

Comment: It isn't working because the DBA didn't give you the right parameter name. Either use a MySQL workbench or HeidiSQL or some such client to have a look for yourself or get him to give you the correct name. Ball is in his court really.

Answer (score 0):

you can pragmatically get the metadata
DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();

ResultSet rs = meta.getProcedureColumns("dbname", "owner", "ProcedureName", "%");

while(rs.next(){

rs.getString(4) ;//will return the parametername

}